# Giving other classes control of a Windows Form Object

Tags: c#

I´m searching for the best way to control an object of my Windows Form, from another Class.
Pls don´t answer, if your answer is "This is not the way you do it in OOP Languages!".
Pls take care of what I need:

I have a invisible Progress Bar in my Windows Form. If I press a button on my Windows Form, a file should be loaded and the Progress Bar should perform some steps...
As the file loading operation is pretty complex, I load it from an own class which is for files of a certain type.
Like:

```
void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MapFiles.ProcessFile()
}
```

Now in the ProcessFile method I want to take control to the ProgressBar in my Form.
It works, if I make the ProgessBar public and static. But this has some grievances. You can´t control the element in the Form Designer anymore.

It would be easy, if I could just access a instanced object of my Form. But I don´t know how since the form is initialized with:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

I didn't wanna do something with Inheritance here, because the MapFiles do not really have anything to do with the Form1...

Is there another / the best way to take control over this ProgressBar from another Class?

Comment: Create an event on your worker class that Form1 can subscribe to and use to receive progress bar updates.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "This is not the way you do it in modern languages", and there's a reason for that. It breaks encapsulation. Your class that does the file load shouldn't need to know that your form happens to use a progress bar control. If you decide to change your form to use a different control, then the file load code shouldn't need to change. Use a technique that separates the concept of progress in a file load from the concept of how you happen to display that progress.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just pass a reference to the progress bar into your `ProcessFile` method:

```
MapFiles.ProcessFile(progressBar1);
```

Then you can access it from your class, for example:

```
ProcessFile(ProgressBar progressBar1)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
}
```

NOTE: As you have said, this probably isn't the best way. But you have made your specific requirements clear so this is my suggestion to give your class control over the progress bar

Comment: you've piqued my interest. What would be YOUR best solution? ;)

Comment: @user2334932: Probably some sort of event, like ByteBlast has suggested. That way you are not tying any UI elements to your class, which makes it more reusable

Comment: Okay I still prefer your answer. But it does not work like that. I learned some time ago, that what you did with "ProcessFile(ProgressBar progressBar1)" is making a new local variable called "progressBar1". It does not even affect the progressBar in my Form...

Comment: @user2334932: I have tested this, and it does work. You must be doing something else that is preventing the update. If you are doing all your processing on the main UI thread then you wont see the update until afterwards (you should be using anoher thread, e.g. background worker and reporting the progress). If you are disabling some elements then that could also be a problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go around passing references to your form you can make something like this.

```
public static class FormSharer
{
   public static YourFormClass Form {get; set;}
}
```

in your form load event you do

```
FormSharer.Form = this;
```

and from every other class you just reference FormSharer.Form

That being said, its not a very good idea to do this. But then again you need it so that's that.

Comment: No, he doesn't need it.  It's a bad idea for a reason, and there are lots of appropriate ways to go about solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for as long as your class in the same project you can  do this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void AccessForm() 
    {
       var thatForm = (Form1)Form.ActiveForm;

        var progressBar = thatForm.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(a => a.Name =="progressBar1").FirstOrDefault();
        MessageBox.Show(progressBar.Name);

    }

}
```

I updated my answer so you do not have to make any control public

Comment: Even if the variable representing the control isn't public, this is still accessing the control outside of the forms definition, and *that* is what is poor design, regardless of whether you use the named variable or not.

Comment: he specifically asked not to criticize his approach and my answer how you access form instance matches "Giving other classes control of a Windows Form Object" for his case, without even changing signature of MapFiles.ProcessFile()

Comment: 1) That doesn't mean you can't suggest a *proper* approach anyway.  He didn't say he was *demanding* an improper approach 2) You were the one saying that this is preferable to making a control public.  It's really not, it's just as bad.  At least recognize that it's horrible practice rather than giving the impression that it's not.  3) There was no requirement given that the signature of `ProcessFile` not be changed.

Comment: i think you are way off topic of this question  here

Comment: How so?  You think that discussing proper design for a given problem is generally offtopic on a programming q/a site.  How unfortunate.  Analyzing the effectiveness of the design of a solution to any given problem should be a force of habit for any good developer, not something to ignore and refuse to participate in.

Comment: you should read his question again: Pls don´t answer, if your answer is "This is not the way you do it in OOP Languages!"

Comment: 1) This isn't an answer, it's a comment.  2) It's not even directed at the OP, it's directed at *you*.  Posting something like that *as an answer* wouldn't be an appropriate answer, because it's not solving the problem.  An answer should simply show how to do something like this correctly.  Regardless, my major criticism was that you were implying that this isn't problematic, isn't bad practice, or is generally better than making the variable for the control public.  None of that is true.  If it at least recognizes that I wouldn't have commented.

Comment: The OP also said: "Is there another / the best way to" so he *is* looking for the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Progress` class to handle this very effectively.

Just start out defining a `Progress` object in your click handler in which it indicates how to update progress; in this case, by updating the value of the progress bar.

Then pass that `Progress` instance`*as an`IProgress` instance* to your worker.

The worker can then use `Report` to indicate progress.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(
        percent => progressbar1.Value = percent);
    DoStuff(progress);
}

private void DoStuff(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            progress.Report(i);
            Thread.Sleep(200); //placeholder for real work
        }
    });
}
```

Best of all the `Progress` class even captures the current `SynchronizationContext` and uses that when invoking the progress changed event, so the event will be able to fire in the UI thread even if you call `Report` from some other thread.